What is the Easiest Way to Deploy Keycloak?
I am looking to deploy Keycloak for my project, but I am relatively new to both Keycloak and deployment processes in general. Could anyone suggest the simplest method to get Keycloak up and running?
I am open to using cloud services if they simplify the process.
I have some basic experience with Docker.
I am using a Linux-based system for my development environment.
Any step-by-step guides, tools that you could recommend would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I attempted to deploy Keycloak using Azure, but I ran into several issues and couldn't get it to work as expected.

Since this post is not about programming, it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It may be on-topic on devpos.

I will share with you few ways to deploy keycloak on azure from my end. One is using Kubernetes other using containers instance and third is using webapp
To setup keycloak on ACI using image stored in ACR you can follow below steps-
Create an ACR if you don’t have one:
az acr create --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myRegistry --sku Basic



once active enable admin login from portal in your acr or using CLI
az acr update --name myRegistry --admin-enabled true



login to acr
az acr login --name myRegistry



Push the Keycloak image to ACR
I am using jboss image
docker pull jboss/keycloak
docker tag jboss/keycloak myRegistry.azurecr.io/keycloak
docker push myRegistry.azurecr.io/keycloak



Create a Container App

Go to the Azure portal, and create a new Container App.
Select the appropriate subscription, resource group, and region.
Choose the ACR as the source for your container images.
Select the myRegistry.azurecr.io/keycloak image you pushed earlier.
Set up the required environment variables for Keycloak, such as KEYCLOAK_USER and KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD while setup. Configure the CPU, memory, and other network setting and deploy


Once deployed, you can verify the same using the app url

Other alternative methods-
Using azure webapp
Here , I am using the same jboss/keycloak image in my acr and create the webapp. When setting up, select docker container

and under docker tab choose your acr where you kept the keycloak image


You don’t have to put any startup command. Choose your type of networking and deploy

and similar way you can access your keycloak using the app url

alternative way reference-
keycloak on webapp
Now suppose you want to deploy using AKS,
use this link # keycloak helm chart values.yaml

Once deployed, now if you want to change the version
first, identify the Keycloak Helm release: helm list -A
then verify if your keycloak is deployed as stateful or not using kubectl get statefulsets -A
This command will list all StatefulSets across all namespaces. Look for Keycloak in the output. Now that you know that your Keycloak deployment is deployed as a StatefulSet, not a Deployment.
update the Keycloak image in a StatefulSet, use the following command:
kubectl set image statefulset/keycloak keycloak=docker.io/bitnami/keycloak:23.0.6-debian-11-r4 -n default



This command specifies the image for the keycloak container within the keycloak StatefulSet in the default namespace.
You can verify the progress using
kubectl rollout status statefulset/keycloak -n default



Finally after rollout is complete verify
kubectl get pods -l app.kubernetes.io/name=keycloak -n default -o=jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}"



There you go-
originally when initially deployed, it was at 23.0.7

now it is at 23.0.6 debian-11-r4

pods are up as well

